# angular moment date time picker timezone directive issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-moment

The following code shows a date time picker in a form and i am using angular-moment-picker plugin as picker. When i pick a certain date/time it shows right time in the picker input box, but after the form is submitted the time entered in db is lagging behind. So i used a timezone directive from a stackoverflow answer. But it throws viewValue.getMinutes is not a function error

```
<div moment-picker="startTime" class="form-control"  name="startTime" 
  ng-model="shiftTimings.startTime" format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" datepicker-localdate > 
     {{ startTime }} </div>
```

Directive

```
app.directive('datepickerLocaldate', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'A',
            require: ['ngModel'],
            link: link
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
            var ngModelController = ctrls[0];

            ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {

                viewValue.setMinutes(viewValue.getMinutes() - viewValue.getTimezoneOffset());

                return viewValue.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
            });


            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
                if (!modelValue) {
                    return undefined;
                }

                var dt = new Date(modelValue);

                dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
                return dt;
            });
        }
}]);
```

Comment: I guess the issue is something related to the data which need to gets saved in the Database, not related to the DOM. Directives are the DOM decorative. I guess instead of using directive for, write a simple function to process the data, and pass it to the service which save the data....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened with me too ! When javascript dates are passsed to browser , The browser uses GMT for the time that is why your time is lagging in db .

I have used a workaround with moment. Instead of passing javascript date object i am formatting my date with moment before passing it to backed .

So    `shiftTimings.startTime` Can be manipulated with moment like this before sending :

```
var tempDate=moment(shiftTimings.startTime).format("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSS") + 'Z';
```

then you can pass `tempDate` to your backend.

Comment: i think this will work. Will check now and let you know soon. Just curious that is why asking this. In case say i use a directive, why it throws viewValue.getMinutes is not a function ?

Comment: your viewValue is a proper date object ? beacuse getMintes() works on javascript date object.